# Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings

Tags: react-native

i m using react-navigation/drawer library with also other needed libraries , but my app not working. Emulator shows pop up "close App" again and again.Even i could not found any warning or error except above.further details given below.Now help me with your expert solution, Thanks All!

PS E:\My Final Year Project\Home_Pages> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 999 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug
>   12:05:26 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
>   12:05:28 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '420070b9d8ac5489' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   12:05:28 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-J327T1 - 7.0' for app:debug
>   12:05:28 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '420070b9d8ac5489'
>   12:05:28 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '420070b9d8ac5489'
>   12:05:28 D/ddms: Reading file permision of E:\My Final Year Project\Home_Pages\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
>   12:05:30 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   12:05:41 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '420070b9d8ac5489' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   12:05:41 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   12:05:41 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   12:05:42 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '420070b9d8ac5489' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   12:05:42 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 26s
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "420070b9d8ac5489"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.home_pages/.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }

Comment: tell me if it has updated issues,

Comment: If updated issues , so kindly given me a complete guide lines for update it.

Comment: Thanks a lot friends